# angular grep or filter to get an object given an ID

Tags: angularjs, json, filter

I have a json array of Category objects from my database. (I am storing it in vm.data in my controller, which is bound to an angular repeater.)

Now I need to go back and get the SubCats in each category using the 'Category' field in each SubCat.

Here is my generic data getter:

```
function getData(params, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'database.php',
        params: params
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        callback(response.data);

    });
}
```

So, to get my Categories, I do:

```
function getCats() {
    var params = {};
    params.table = "Categories";
    getData(params,buildCats);
};
```

which calls back to

```
function buildCats(data) {
    vm.data = data;
    $.each(vm.data,function(index,value){
        getSubCat(value.uID);
    });
};
```

then, one by one it gets the SubCats:

```
function getSubCat(categoryId) {
    var params = {};
    params.table = "SubCats";
    params.where_field = "Category";
    params.where_value = categoryId;
    getData(params, buildSubCat);
};
```

which calls back to this: (I no longer have the Category Id, so I have to go looking for it in my SubCat data)

```
function buildSubCat(data) {
    var categoryId = data[0].Category;
    $filter('filter')(vm.data, function(el){
        el.uID==categoryId; 
    }, true).SubCats = data;
}
```

and it is here I am running into trouble.

I need to get hold of the unique Category object in vm.data **- the actual object, not a copy of it -** whose uID equals the ID of the SubCats I am currently processing, then ADD the current SubCat object to it. The above does not work. At least, I never see the SubCats within the Categories in vm.data.

I tried to pull it apart, like this:

```
var foo = $filter('filter')(vm.data, function(el){
    el.uID==categoryId; 
}, true);
foo.SubCats = data;
```

but **foo is new instance of the Category object, not a reference to the one in vm.data**, so my adding  is not affecting vm.data.
I suppose I could try to replace vm.data[n] with foo, but this seems a poor practice.

How can I asynchronously retrieve the Categories and SubCats and combine them?

Something tickling the back of my brain tells me I should be passing the actual Category object into the getData, so it is directly available in the callback, but I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out a solution, just not sure if it's the best.

I accept a third param to pass the target object into the getData function:

```
function getData(params, target, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php',
        params: params
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        callback(target, response.data);

    });
}
```

In my getCats, I pass vm.data as the target param (though there is no need to, as will be seen in a moment).

```
function getCats() {
    var params = {};
    params.table = "Categories";
    params.sort_field = "Order";
    params.sort_dir = "ASC";
    getData(params, vm.data, buildCats);
};
```

Now, I **should** be able to do this:

```
function buildCats(target, data) {
    target = data;
    $.each(target,function(index, catObj){
        getSubCat(catObj);
    });
};
```

But for some reason it does not work. target seems to have lost its reference to vm.data. Bonus points if you can figure out what went wrong.

But that's OK - I don't need the target - I can assign the results **directly** to vm.data:

```
function buildCats(target, data) {
    vm.data = data;
    $.each(vm.data,function(index, catObj){
        getSubCat(catObj);
    });
};
```

I can now pass the actual Category object itself to the getSubCat call:

```
function getSubCat(categoryObject) {

    var params = {};
    params.table = "SubCats";
    params.where_field = "Category";
    params.where_value = categoryObject.uID;
    params.sort_field = "Order";
    params.sort_dir = "ASC";
    getData(params, categoryObject, buildSubCat);
};
```

which means I now have the **actual** object in the callback:

```
function buildSubCat(categoryObject, data) {
    categoryObject.SubCats = data;
};
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="category" ng-repeat="cat in vm.data">
    <h2>{{cat.Name}}</h2>
    <div class="subcategory" ng-repeat="SubCat in cat.SubCats">
        <h3>{{SubCat.Name}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```